# extract no of click month wise

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL. Here is my schema:

> bannerstatclick(idBannerStats: integer, Time: Timestamp, idCampaignBanner :char(36))

I am trying to write a query to select the total no of click month wise by using count on idCampaignBanner.
this will not work it will give an error invalid use of group function.
iwill also try this using having clause but it also not work...

```
SELECT count(idCampaignBanner) AS TotalClicks ,max(`Time`) AS maxdate,(min(`Time`) + INTERVAL 30 DAY)as monthly
FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick 
WHERE Time BETWEEN   max(`Time`)  AND (  max(`Time`)- INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (you need `group by` clause if you do aggregation)

```
select count(idCampaignBanner), MONTH(`Time`) as m
from newradium.BannerStatsClick
group by m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  count(idCampaignBanner) AS TotalClicks
, max(`Time`) AS maxdate
, (min(`Time`) + INTERVAL 30 DAY)as monthly
FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick 
WHERE Time <= (Select max(`Time`) FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick)
  And Time >= (Select max(`Time`) - INTERVAL 30 DAY FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick)
```

Technically could get rid of "Time <= (Select max(`Time`) FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick)", doesn't really affect the selection. But left in in case you needed different range in future